# can I get Joomla article link that contain a specific plugin?

Tags: php, joomla

I hacked ignite component to tag people to an image and send email to them, in the email body I need to insert a link to point to the article that contain this image.

I inserted the image in the article using ignite plugin.

how can I get the article link that contain ignite gallery plugin with categoryid = x

is it possible to get it ?

thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Joomla 1.5:

I'm not positive how this Ignite package works, but from looking at their website it seems that they're pushing galleries into articles on render?  So from that I deduced, they're probably using something like onPrepareContent in their plugin which takes &$article by reference (so it can be modified).  If you were looking to access the article ID in the plugin all you would have to do is use `$article->id`.

However, if you're looking to access the article ID in the component I would think you would just need to know the table that Ignite is storing the information in where it contains the article ID and the category ID.  Then when you know the table you should just be able to query it and return article id where categoryid=x.  If you haven't written a query before in Joomla this should help: [How to use the database classes in your script](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_database_classes_in_your_script).

If you have any more specific information please tell because it may help someone else who has used Ignite give you a better answer.

Comment: thank you aupdo, I'm trying to access it from the admin part of the component code, they do not have a table to store articleID on it
it stored inside the article content.

do you have any other idea ?
thanks alot

Comment: It seems from what you say and from more that I read that there is no real association between category ID and article ID as you can just arbitrarily use their embed code on any article.

The only way I can see you being able to know the article ID is within the content plugin that probably parses `$article->text` and looks for Ignite's embed code.  You'd have to use `$article->id` in the portion of the plugin where it has found a match for the Ignite embed code.  Unfortunately, I don't think that will help you get where you want to be.